# jQuery - event handlers on a class where the elements are subsequently created by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, event-handling

I've been doing this to create a handler every time an element is created (rh differs each time, of course):

```
$('#'+rh).on('click', function (e) {...
```

I wanted to try to create just one handler for the class `rh` which will apply to all subsequently created elements in that class. I've tried this, but it hasn't worked:

```
$('.rh').on('click', function (e) {...
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought `on` had a retrospective effect (and the api.jQuery.com site is down).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go for a event delegation. As you're creating them dynamically, so you need event delegation (aka, live event) on them.

```
$('#container').on('click', '.rh', function (e) {...
```

here `#container` is the parent of created elements which belongs on DOM at page load. You may have something else.

Read more about **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

There is another option called [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)

```
$('#container').delegate('.rh', 'click', function (e) {...
```

I'd go for `.on()`.

Comment: Nice! That works well. Would it be more efficient to choose a smaller element than body, or does it make no difference?  - You just modified your post to answer my question :)